# Should I use a service instead of a background activity?

Tags: android, service

Now I have a mp3 player that can play music, and I'm wondering should i use service instead of activity.

I have two ways to play music in background (continues to play when user press back button)

1. When user press back button, I override `onBackPressed()` and move the activity to background like the way user press home button, so when user launch my app again, it will be displayed as expected.
2. I read some article about overriding `onBackPressed()` and some people said that it would not a good way to do some works in background, the better way is using service. :). So my idea is when user press back button, I call `finish()` to destroy and release the activity, then I create a service that can play music from the point that activity is finished and a notification to help user can go back the main activity.

I think the first approach is very simple and easy to implement but not recommended. And the second one is better but more complex and I don't think this way optimizes memory rather then the first one.

I'm very wondering about which one I should use. Please tell me the better one among two ways above or if you have experience working on something similar lately, please tell your approach in this situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you should use a service.

Please refer to the [media player guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Comment: Thank you, but could you please tell me why the first approach is not good?.

Comment: I really doubt that your first approach could work properly. The activities that are in the background are managed by the OS, not by the developer.

If you're looking to do some "background" work for a long period of time you have to assure that, in fact, that work is going to get done. Since you do not know when it's going to be finished (as you're implementing an MP3 player) your best bet is a service (instead of an AsyncTask, for example).

Comment: So the only reason is because we don't know when our app is killed by OS? and it is not because of optimizing memory?

Comment: I don't think that there would be a difference in what memory usage concerns, but I could be wrong about that. But keep in mind that an Activity is not proper for what you're trying to accomplish. Activities are not ideal for performing background work, they are suited for user interaction, and a background MP3 player isn't the case.

Comment: Great, I'm going to try that. thanks so much and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Service for that.

And ideally you should use a [Ongoing Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)

This will prevent your service from being killed by the System.

Look at the [mediaplayer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)